# A basic question for holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider $f = u + iv$, if $u,v$ are differentiable, and $\partial f/\partial {\overline{z}} = 0$, then $f$ is holomorphic.
I would like to know if $u,v$ are less smooth, for example they are just $C^1$, then the previous statement holds. Because any derivative of $f$ exists, is it means that $u,v$ are actually smooth, for example $u_{xx}$ exists?

Comment: Look up: [Looman-Menchoff theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looman%E2%80%93Menchoff_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

The cannot be just $C^1$. Since $f$ is holomorphic, it is smooth, and therefore $u$ and $v$ are smooth too.

Comment: Is it same to say if u,v satisfies Cauchy Riemann equation, then they are smooth? Even if at first, we know nothing about smoothness of u and v except  u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y exists.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.